# how to change date from gregorian to shamsi in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, persian

I want to change date from Gregorian to shamsi in JavaScript. I am reading data from model with ajax so datetime field is Gregorian but I want to display shamsi date to user .and I want to use this shamsi date instead of result.datetime in the code below, but I don't know how to do this.

```
 function f2() {

    var ID = $("#sel").val();
   $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/GetPredict",
        data: { ID: ID },
        type: "post",
        success: function (value) {
            res = JSON.parse(value);
            $("#mm").empty();
            $("#mdiv").empty();
            $("#mm").append("<tr><td align='center'> بازی</td><td align='center'>تاریخ</td><td align='center'>پیش بینی شما</td><td align='center'>امتیاز کسب شده</td></tr>");
            $.each(res, function (idx, result) {

                $("#mm").append("<tr><td align='center'>" + result.game + "</td><td align='center'>" + ToJavaScriptDate(result.datetime) + "</td><td align='center'>" + result.predict + "</td><td align='center'>" + result.score + "</td></tr>");

            })
            if (res!=null) {
                $("#mdiv").append("<a style='color:red' href='../Account/PdfGenerator?ID=" + ID + "'><img src='../img/pdf.png' /></a>");
            }
        }
    })
}
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
    alert('ok')
    var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
    var results = pattern.exec(value);
    var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
    alert(dt)
    var pc_fa = $.calendars.instance('persian', 'fa');
    var jdate33 = pc_fa.fromJSDate(new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()));
    return jdate33;

}


</script>
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimal working example that illustrates your problem: what you do, what you get, what you want to get.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [Keith Wood library](https://github.com/kbwood/calendars) for the conversion:

```
var pc_fa = $.calendars.instance('persian', 'fa');
alert("Current date: " + pc_fa.fromJSDate(new Date()));
```

See [here](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsRef.html) for documentation. Working example: [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1oyhe90/).

Comment: @myname, thanks, checked, corrected added link to a jfiddle.

Comment: @myname: does the updated answer solve your problem?

Comment: See also here another simple built-in method to do the conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421825/how-to-convert-persian-jalali-dates-to-other-18-calendar-dates-in-javascript-w