# convert date shamsi to miladi in js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a date in this format
1379/10/02
Now I want to turn this date into AD
That is, the date 2000/4/29

I also use the **momentJs** library
Please help me if possible by using this library
Thank you for your time

Comment: Try this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71421825/how-to-convert-persian-jalali-dates-to-other-18-calendar-dates-in-javascript-w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jalaali-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jalaali-js) or [moment-jalaali](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-jalaali) or [jalali-date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jalali-date) ([via](/a/43850771)) or [Ali Amini's](/a/51135200) or [Mohsen Alyafei's solution](/q/71421825). Or draw inspiration from [related questions](/questions/tagged/jalali-calendar%2Bjavascript?tab=Votes). People not knowing Persian culture can get confused by the multiple names for the calendar - Jalali, Persian, Khorshidi, Shamsi. Maybe you can elaborate the differences a bit?

Here is a modern solution using the Skypack CDN for easy npm package access in the browser. Just remember to always declare your variables with const/let/var and no global ones inside es6-modules:

```html
<script type="module">
import jalaali from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/jalaali-js'
import jMoment from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/moment-jalaali'


// jalaali-js
let g = jalaali.toGregorian(1379, 2, 10);
let j = jalaali.toJalaali(new Date(2000, 4-1, 29)) // january is month 0

// moment-jalaali
let moment = jMoment('1379/2/10', 'jYYYY/jM/jD') // Parse a Jalaali/Shamsi date
let gregorian = moment.format('jYYYY/jM/jD [is] YYYY/M/D')


console.log('jalaali-js version:',g,j,'moment-jalaali version: ', gregorian)
</script>
```